# Package not Installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, chatterbot

I am trying to make an AI bot.

When I go into the terminal, I type `pip install chatterbot`. It is giving an error. It is showing this - pip :

```
The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that  
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

+ pip install chatterbot
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

### Windows

This is most relevant to this question.
Try `python -m pip install ...`

If this does not work, did you check the box while installing python that says "Install PIP" (it is the default) or did you change it?

If yes, then add `pip` to your path.

### Linux Distros

This part is for future readers.
On Linux, you have to install `pip` separately.

After you have installed python:

```bash
sudo apt install python3
```

Use:

```bash
sudo apt install pip3
```

And then you can use `pip` by using `pip3`.